# BufferedWriter not writing even after flushing and closing?

Tags: java

```
try{
   BufferedWriter writer  = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("~/Desktop/raw/test.txt")));
   writer.write("TEST");
   writer.close();
} catch (Exception e){

}
```

This code doesnt seem to write to the file thats called `test.txt` at all. I have confirmed that it exists in `~/Desktop/raw/test.txt` and it doesnt throw any exception.

what could be the issue?

Comment: Never ignore Exception. Maybe you'll have the message that'll explain all : `e.printStackTrace();` Try, and tell us

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've shown us.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, `BufferedWriter` can't read paths with `~`. Thats 30 minute down the drain for a simple fix.